# Fake S3 Service for testing

Tags: java, amazon-s3, integration-testing, jets3t

I have built a swing application that will upload a user's data onto S3. I am using the jets3t library to upload and interact with the S3 service. In order for me to do my testing, is there any way for me to stub out calls to S3 and make the jets3t library hit the stubs?

Comment: you may be interested in [ymock](http://www.ymock.com) library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since S3 does not charge you too heftily, its just easier to test against the real thing. There isn't any library out there that does all the things that s3 does and to write such a thing would take a while.

So we decided to test directly, and changed our test cases to use S3 sparingly, but yet try out all the combinations.

Comment: Hitting S3 in tests implies that those tests will be flaky and/or slow.

Comment: There's a rubygem called fakes3 that does exactly this.

Comment: Ideally tests should be able to be run in isolation and not be dependent on external resources.